# Why doesn't vanity create vanity_experiments.rb and similar in app/models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vanity

I've create and run my vanity migrations and I can see the resulting tables in `schema.rb` and the `rails console`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
 => ["schema_migrations", "pages", "users", "areas", "roles", "assignments", "categories", "heuristics", "references", "footnotes", "products", "orders", "vanity_metrics", "vanity_metric_values", "vanity_experiments", "vanity_conversions", "vanity_participants"]
```

Why then has it not created `vanity_experiments.rb` and similar files in `app/models`?

I understand vanity will be using Redis not my PostgreSQL to store the data, but Rails still maps each table to a model, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanity supports multiple adapters, including ActiveRecord.  My guess is that the generator creates these migrations in case you're using the ActiveRecord adapter.

See http://vanity.labnotes.org/configuring.html for more info.

Comment: Yup - no need for the migrations if you're using a non-AR adapter. (If you were using the AR adapter, then the models live in the gem source, not in `app/models/`.)